# Services decide to shutdown from time to time

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze, isp, shutdown

I've a debian squeeze server with nginx, php5-fpm and mysql. All this services from some point started to shutdown at random time. And they not seem to crash or something, syslog:

```
Feb 14 14:02:14 xxx mysqld: 130214 14:02:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
```

There is also an isp control panel, and around this shoutdowns there is some cron from isp manager running.
What can cause that or where should I look to find out more information?

Comment: Perhaps it's `logrotate`

Comment: @fuero how can I check if it's `logrotate`?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the way it shutdowns here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-shutdown.html

It seems like its a normal shutdown referenced by a user or a process - maybe the cron.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpm7%2Fm7enablelogs.html
Look at this options - maybe you can set the following option:

```
"log=loggingname.log" in the my.cnf file
```

This should record all requests/user connections and maybe you can see which process kills or shutdown the server. 
I am pretty sure its no bug you just have to find out which kills the process